# How to make spring boot msa with querydsl

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, microservices, querydsl

I am using Spring Boot version 3.0.2 and Gleddle version 7.6.1.

When I do a clean build in Gleddle, I get the
'Attempt to recreate a file for type com.joshua.system.common.audit.QTimeEntity'
I keep getting the error message 'Attempting to recreate a file for type com.joshua.system.common.audit.QTime.Entity' and I was wondering if you could tell me what is wrong with the gridle file I created.

Below is the griddle file I created.

Is the querydsl Qfile generation much different since Spring Boot 3.0.x?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

this is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.10.RELEASE"
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.joshua'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
ext {
    // set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.3")
    set('springCloudVersion', "2022.0.1")
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.0'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'

    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'



    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.8'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:2.2.8.RELEASE'

    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'




    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'

    annotationProcessor(
            "org.projectlombok:lombok",
            "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final",
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta",
            "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api",
            "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api"
    )

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
// QueryDSL
def querydslDir = "$buildDir/generated/querydsl"

querydsl {
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = querydslDir
}
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir querydslDir
}
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath
}
compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude the generated Q-classes from the compiler analysis so that they do not participate in the re-generation. This can be done, for example, using the `exclude` parameter in the `compileQuerydsl` block:

```
compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
    options.compilerArgs += ['-proc:none']
    source = fileTree(querydslDir)
    include("org/example/spring/database/entity/**")
    exclude("org/example/spring/database/entity/Q*")
}
```